# How not to miss a signal

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I have this code, written in qt 5.15:

```cpp
Widget::Widget()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://example.com")));
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &Widget::replyFinished));

}
void Widget::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    // some processing here
    qDebug() << reply.readAll();
}
```

It works as expected, but I wonder, **is there a risk to miss the signal emmited by `QNetworkReply`?**

I tested that if I had some delay (with `QThread::sleep(1);`) between the `get` and the `connect`, `replyFinished` is not called.

**Is there a method to ask an object to resend a signal if it has been missed?**

Comment: Re. `"...if I had some delay (1 sec) between the get and the connect, replyFinished is not called."`: please edit your question to show how you implement that delay.  Is it a blocking delay or does it make use of the event loop (e.g. a `QTimer`)?

Comment: There's no way to know that a signal has been missed, so there's no way to request that it be resent.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is some sort of message queue that holds onto the message until the consumer is ready to read it. You could implement something like that if you want. But it seems overkill for the specific example that you're citing.

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with the accepted answer: if you remove `QThread::sleep(1)` (that was added only to "*trigger a race condition*"), then the `if (reply->bytesAvailable() > 0)` will always return false. It provides no guard against anything.

---

First, a small detour to the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details)

*A more involved example, assuming the manager is already existent, can be:*

```
 QNetworkRequest request;
 request.setUrl(QUrl("http://qt-project.org"));
 request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");

 QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
 connect(reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &MyClass::slotReadyRead);
 connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::errorOccurred,
         this, &MyClass::slotError);
 connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors,
         this, &MyClass::slotSslErrors);
```

Like you, they first send a `get` request, then connect signals.
They would not provide a buggy sample in their doc, meaning it was deemed safe for production: no chance signals will be lost because data is received before the connection is established.
That is the very reason why `if (reply->bytesAvailable() > 0)` will always return false BTW; a network is just thousands of times too slow for it to be otherwise.

---

If you still want to be careful, the correct approach is to connect the `finished` signal to your slot **before** sending the request.
That way, even if you miss all the `readyRead` signals, your slot will still be called at least once (since the connection was made before).

I have tweaked your code a bit to make it compile and show:

1. The `if (reply->bytesAvailable() > 0)` returns false (text `Call from if` is never displayed).
2. All the reply is called from the `readyRead` connection.
3. The `finished` signal triggers the last call to `replyFinished` after everything is received; `replyFinished` is called using the same pointer to `QNetworkReply` as the rest.
   That pointer has, for the reasons I detailed above (no signal is lost so everything gets consummed in point 2), nothing to read on that final call.

Here is the tweaked code:

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
//Safety is assured by making the following connection
//before any http request is sent.
    connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Widget::replyFinished);
    QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, 
        [=]() { qDebug() << "Called from readyRead"; this->replyFinished(reply); }
    );
    if (reply->bytesAvailable() > 0) {
        qDebug() << "Call from if";
        replyFinished(reply);
    }
}
void Widget::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QString strReply = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << (void*)reply << " read " << strReply.length() << " characters";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QNetworkReply sends the signal from another thread, so there is indeed a possible race condition here.

To guard against it, you can do this:

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://example.com")));
    QThread::sleep(1); // trigger race condition
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &Widget::replyFinished));
    if (reply->bytesAvailable() > 0) replyFinished(reply);

}
```

Note that your *replyFinished* can get called twice.

Also,`readyRead` does not mean entire reply has arrived, so it does *not* mean "reply finished".

Comment: @hyde, what is it that you say about signals being sent from another thread causing a race condition?

Comment: @Atmo Read the question. It seems `get()` starts doing the request immediately, and sends signal when done. If connect is not done yet, signal is lost. At least as reported in the question... Did not test myself.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the call to `QNetworkAccessManager::get` merely 'stages' the request: nothing of importance occurs until control is passed back to the Qt event loop.

Consider the code snippet...

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk")));
dummy_delay();
QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, qApp,
                 [&]()
                   {
                     std::log << "finished: error = " << reply->error() << '\n';
                     qApp->quit();
                   });
```

With the following implementation of `dummy_delay`...

```
void dummy_delay ()
{

    /*
     * Blocking (i.e. no events processed) sleep for 10 seconds.
     */
    QThread::sleep(10);
}
```

the lambda is called correctly when the `finished` signal is emitted: i.e. no signal is lost despite the delay (and regardless of the delay duration -- I tested up to 1 minute).  With the next implementation however...

```
void dummy_delay ()
{

    /*
     * Process events for 10 seconds.
     */
    QEventLoop el;
    QTimer::singleShot(10000, [&]{ el.quit(); });
    el.exec();
}
```

control returns to the event loop and -- assuming the download takes less than 10s -- the `finished` signal is 'lost' and the lambda never called.

So it's safe to call `connect` after the `get` request provided the intervening code does not, at any point, return control to the event loop.

[Note that the above is purely empirical as I haven't had a chance to study the relevant Qt source code yet.]