# Race condition with Qt connections

Tags: multithreading, qt, http, networking, race-condition

I'm looking at [Qt's example HTTP client](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtnetwork-http-example.html) provided with Qt Creator.

- `reply` is a [`QScopedPointer<QNetworkReply>`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscopedpointer.html).
- `qnam` is a [`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)
- `url` is a `QString` url.

In the example code, an HTTP request is made before connecting the corresponding signals to their slots:

```
reply.reset(qnam.get(QNetworkRequest(url)));

connect(reply.get(), &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &HttpWindow::httpFinished);
connect(reply.get(), &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &HttpWindow::httpReadyRead);

#if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
connect(reply.get(), &QNetworkReply::sslErrors, this, &HttpWindow::sslErrors);
#endif
```

This ordering is necessary because `connect` requires the reply pointer, which is set in the first line:

```
reply.reset(qnam.get(QNetworkRequest(url)));
```

But what prevents `QNetworkReply::finished`, `QIODevice::readyRead`, or `QNetworkReply::sslErrors` from being emitted before the connection is made?

Isn't the HTTP request made as soon as `qnam.get` is called?

Does it make any difference if `qnam` lives in a separate thread?

Comment: Re, "Does it make any difference if `qnam` is located on a separate thread?" I would not say, "located on" because a thread is not a location, but if you are talking about the network access manager's [_thread affinity_](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity), then yes, that appears to matter. I'm not a Qt person, but the [documentation for QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details) says that it "can only be used from the thread it belongs to." (I'm _guessing_ that "belongs to" and "affinity" are different names for the same relationship.)

Comment: I changed "located on" to "lives in." Thanks. If anyone wants to suggest different wording, feel free. "Lives in" is correct, short, and I think we all understand what it means.

Comment: @Bobby That note indicates that QNetworkAccessManager can only be used (aka, call its functions) from the thread it belongs (when created by an object living in another thread, or by using `moveToThread()` when called *within* that QThread). So, the assumption is that `qnam.get()` will be done in the *proper* thread, and any further signal for that reply will be emitted from the same thread. About your question, QNAM seems to immediately *send* the request, but this doesn't mean that its result (whatever it may be) from the network stack will be immediately processed by Qt, except maybe for »

Comment: @Bobby » the case in which the request itself is malformed). From what I can understand from the sources, Qt itself connects the signals of the reply (after it has been created) to the QNAM related slots (search for `QNetworkAccessManagerPrivate::postProcess()` in the sources). In any case, you can still check the reply's `error()`, `isFinished()` and possibly even `waitForReadyRead(0)`. But I'd suggest you to do further testing before adding unnecessary calls by default. Also, remember that network access is quite slow, and you're you're connecting signals right after the request has been »

Comment: @Bobby » created. I seem to remember that some requests use separate threads, but I'm not completely sure, but, in any case: if they are not using threading, it means that the request is actually sent as soon as the event loop gains control back; if not, the very condition of creating a QThread and starting it will probably delay the request for a safe amount of time, considering the aforementioned slowness. Also, see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75951289).

Comment: Another option is to listen for the QNetworkAccessManager's own `finished` and `sslErrors` signals, rather than QNetworkReply's. The problem there of course is that the QNetworkAccessManager may be used for other requests too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How not to miss a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951289/how-not-to-miss-a-signal)

Comment: According to that linked post issue, which I have not tested myself, nothing prevents the signals from being emitted too soon. But it also seems, that it is practically impossible for QNAM internal thread to not need to wait for IO, and this thread is practically quaranteed to be able to connect to the signals before they are emitted. But it is a bit disturbing to think about this... this... faith based synchronization.